# HTML5/JSON : UTF-8 cant read proper characters from json

Tags: ajax, json, html, character-encoding

My HTML5 app is using JSON to fetch data.

The json contact characters like: **ö**

but the output in my browser is like: �

I used the following in HTML5 header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

and used this in the AJAX to read the JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "items.json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
    ..........
```

But its not helping me out. What will be the solution to it?
I even tried "ISO-8859-1" on both places.

Comment: Where is the UTF-8 data stored? In your database? What is the character encoding of the data in the storage location?

Comment: I have json file which holds the data.

Comment: I've had simular issues when the actual text file isn't stored with the proper encoding. You should open the .json file in an editor and save it again in "UTF-8" format.

Comment: Thanks .. it worked .. I just opened the json file in a notepad and saved it with UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your font family that you are using for your site supports the extended characters you are attempting to print.  Then use firebug or something similar to view what character set your backend json service is sending back.  It may not be sending it back.  Also, check to see if firebug is showing the correct character in the JSON response.  It's possible that the problem is even further back than you thought.

Comment: You mean json right?  What does firebug say the response content-type is and character set?

Comment: I just opened the json file in notepad and saved it as UTF-8 format. Problem got fixed.